# Changes not reflected after receiving the intent from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I am doing `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `listView.invalidateViews()` after I get the
receive call if the condition say "blabla" gets true. But still my UI is not getting updated.

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment{

public class FragmentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(getSetting("CurrentView","").equalsIgnoreCase("blabla")){
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.invalidateViews(); //this is not updating the UI.

}
}
```

**NOTE:** I tried to call the same `UserFragment.java` to update the changes by replacing the same fragment again but that's although updating the UI but giving exceptions- `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

My rest of the code in `onReceive` method -

```
UserFragment firstFragment = new UserFragment ();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.headlines_fragment, firstFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit(); //IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure data which is been displayed in the adapter is changed before you call notifydatasetchanged for adapter.

Comment: yes it is getting changed only if I go to some other view and then come back to this view again but not instantly within the same view.

Comment: try calling onCreate(bundle) again, a dirty trick, but works..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment{
public class FragmentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(getSetting("CurrentView","").equalsIgnoreCase("blabla")){
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.invalidateViews(); //this is not updating the UI.
                UserFragment.this.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
}
```

Comment: How do I get `savedInstanceState` as it is cannot be resolved to a variable at that place.

Comment: thats how you do it, make a global variable Bundle bundle; then in onCreate

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                bundle=savedInstanceState;
}


and then call onCreate like UserFragment.this.onCreate(bundle);

Comment: this isn't updating my UI instantly. I have to go and come back again to reflect the changes.

Comment: thanks I resolved my problem by calling my getData() function before notifyDataSetChanged() which gives recent changes and then there is no need to do any call. It gets reloaded instantly.